# Defining a variable using an if statement Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to adapt a date range based on financial year ending in Feb.

So when the Jan-2020 report is run, it needs to calculate the 24 month window to start from 2017/12 (Feb-2018) to 2019/11 (Jan-2020). How do I get the below to calculate dynamically?

```
define v_report_month = 1
define v_report_year = 2020

define v_start_year = if &v_report_month > 1 then &v_report_year - 2  else &v_report_year - 3 end if
define v_start_monthno = if &v_report_month > 1 then &v_report_month - 1  else &v_report_month + 11 end if 
define v_end_year = if v_report_monthno > 2 then v_report_year else v_report_year - 1 end if
define v_end_monthno = if v_report_monthno > 2 then v_report_month - 2 else v_report_monthno + 10 end if
```

When I try running the following below, just get -- "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

```
select
&v_start_year as y
,&v_start_monthno as m
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PL/SQL anonymous block which would be simpler:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    v_report_month   NUMBER := 1;
    v_report_year    NUMBER := 2020;
    v_start_year     NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_start_year :=
        CASE
            WHEN v_report_month > 1 THEN
                v_report_year - 2
            ELSE v_report_year - 3
        END;
    dbms_output.put_line('Start year: '||v_start_year);
END;
/

Start year: 2017


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The same **CASE** expression could be written using **IF-THEN-ELSE**:

```
IF v_report_month > 1 THEN
    v_start_year := v_report_year - 2;
ELSE
    v_start_year := v_report_year - 3;
END IF;
```

If you want to leave the variables which you have defined in SQL*Plus, then you could do it this way:

```
define v_report_month = 1
define v_report_year = 2020

set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    v_report_year   NUMBER;
    v_start_year    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_start_year :=
        CASE
            WHEN &v_report_month > 1 THEN
                &v_report_year - 2
            ELSE &v_report_year - 3
        END;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_start_year);
END;

2017


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: How do I end up calling these variable values in queries? It doesn't look like the value persists when I use my usual "&" phrasing: 
```
select
&v_start_year as y
from dual;
```
Even when I shift the END block to include this statement.

Comment: `&` is `SQL*Plus` substitution variable which prefixes a substitution variable name in a statement. `SQL*Plus` pre-processes the statement and substitutes the variable's value. When you have a complex script or logic then doing all this in SQL*Plus could be tricky. Since you are using conditional statements I prefer PL/SQL.

Comment: If you want to combine both SQL*Plus and PL/SQL, see my update.

Comment: Thanks for the additional example, but what I'm still struggling with is getting the variables defined by PL/SQL to be used outside of the code block? This logic is just meant to be the first part in a larger section where the start and end date variables are updated to represent different time filters in queries that follow.

Comment: There are many ways of getting the variables in and out of PL/SQL. The best way is to put your code in a procedure and use IN/OUT parameters.